# Why can I not call {}.anymethod while I can call [].anymethod?

Tags: javascript, object

For example, if we do this:

```
Array.prototype.method = () => { console.log("method") }
```

Then we can simply call:

```
[].method() // works
```

But in the case of objects:

```
Object.prototype.method = () => { console.log("method") }
```

We get:

```
{}.method() // doesn't work
Object.method() // works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `{}` is interpreted as an empty block rather than an object. Fix this by wrapping it in parentheses:

```js
 

Object.prototype.method = () => console.log("method");

({}).method();
```

Comment: but in case of array

Comment: thanks for your answer it's helpful for me.
but in case of array i don't nee parentheses @ Jack Bashford

Comment: Yes, because `[]` is treated like an array literal. I also never mentioned once in my answer that they were needed around square brackets.